# Autolayout views one after each other in stack

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout

In my view, i have 3 subviews, following one after another

```
------------
|    V1    |
------------
|    V2    |
------------
|    V3    |
------------
```

Now, the V1 - V3, can have different heights (even height 0) depending on content (i can calculate the desired height)

```
------------
|    V1    |
|    V1    |
|    V1    |
------------
------------
|    V3    |
|    V3    |
------------
```

I played with the IB constraints for hours, but cannot figure it right, so i decided to make it pure programmical, but also i'am hitting problems on the constraints.

```
- (void)setupWithContent:(NSDictionary *)content {

    CGFloat width123 = 200.f;

    CGFloat height1 = [content[@"height1"] floatValue];
    CGFloat height2 = [content[@"height2"] floatValue];
    CGFloat height3 = [content[@"height3"] floatValue];

    [self.view addConstraints:...];
    [self.view1 addConstraints:...];
    [self.view2 addConstraints:...];
    [self.view3 addConstraints:...];

}
```

**How to achieve this using programmical constraints (what does needs to be set in IB in programmical case)**

Answer (score 2):

You can do it really simply with the visual formatting language. Here is an example:

```
@interface DAViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *contentView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *yellowView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *purpleView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *brownView;

@end

@implementation DAViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    self.contentView = [self viewWithColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.contentView];

    self.yellowView = [self viewWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.yellowView];

    self.purpleView = [self viewWithColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.purpleView];

    self.brownView = [self viewWithColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.brownView];

    NSDictionary *views = @{@"yellowView" : self.yellowView,
                            @"purpleView" : self.purpleView,
                            @"brownView" : self.brownView};

    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"padding" : @5,
                              @"width123" : @200,
                              @"height1" : @50,
                              @"height2" : @210,
                              @"height3" : @40};

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         multiplier:1.
                                                           constant:0.]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1.
                                                           constant:0.]];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-padding-[yellowView(==height1)][purpleView(==height2)][brownView(==height3)]-padding-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-padding-[yellowView(==width123)]-padding-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-padding-[purpleView(==width123)]-padding-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-padding-[brownView(==width123)]-padding-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
}

- (UIView *)viewWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    view.backgroundColor = color;

    return view;
}

@end
```

Comment: I feel it should be given reference to superview like @"V:|[V1][V2][V3]|" and maybe use relation like >= with <= to get desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the intrinsicContentSize function on each view to return the desired size, and call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize on the view when that desired size changes, the constraints defined in IB should work the way you want.

[Documentation for [UIView intrinsicContentSize]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/intrinsicContentSize)